# Use XServer in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, xserver

I'm using `wicked_pdf` gem to generate pdf files in my Rails application. This gem uses [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) to convert a HTML file to PDF.

The HTML files I'm converting to PDF contains JavaScript used to generate charts. In order to `wkhtmltopdf` properly render those charts I need to set the `use_xserver` option to `true`.

Everything works fine locally. However, when I try it on Heroku, I get the following error message:

```
Error: PDF could not be generated!
Command Error: wkhtmltopdf-amd64: cannot connect to X server
```

Does Heroku runs a X server? Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't run an X-server in the dyno just to generate pdfs. It looks like wkhtmltopdf can be made to run headless, check out these questions:

- [wkhtmltopdf: cannot connect to X server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604625/wkhtmltopdf-cannot-connect-to-x-server)
- [wkhtmltopdf extremely slow on Debian without X-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290958/wkhtmltopdf-extremely-slow-on-debian-without-x-server)

Comment: In order to do that, I would need to install `xvfb` in Heroku. Is it possible? Looks like it has a lot of dependencies, and I couldn't find a binary to include on my project.